# How to configure an AWS Elastic IP to point to an OpenShift Origin running pod?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

We have set up OpenShift Origin on AWS using [this handy guide](https://sysdig.com/blog/deploy-openshift-aws/).  Our eventual
hope is to have some pods running REST or similar services that we can access
for development purposes.  Thus, we don't need DNS or anything like that at this
point, just a public IP with open ports that points to one of our running pods.
Our first proof of concept is trying to get a jenkins (or even just httpd!) pod
that's running inside OpenShift to be exposed via an allocated Elastic IP.

I'm not a network engineer by any stretch, but I was able to successuflly get
an Elastic IP connected to one of my OpenShift "worker" instances, which I
tested by sshing to the public IP allocated to the Elastic IP.  At this point
we're struggling to figure out how to make a pod visible that allocated Elastic IP,
owever.  We've tried a kubernetes LoadBalancer service, a kubernetes Ingress, 
and configuring an AWS Network Load Balancer, all without being able to
successfully connect to 18.2XX.YYY.ZZZ:8080 (my public IP).

The most promising success was using `oc port-forward` seemed to get at least part way
through, but frustratingly hangs without returning:

```
$ oc port-forward --loglevel=7 jenkins-2-c1hq2 8080 -n my-project
I0222 19:20:47.708145   73184 loader.go:354] Config loaded from file /home/username/.kube/config
I0222 19:20:47.708979   73184 round_trippers.go:383] GET https://ec2-18-2AA-BBB-CCC.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8443/api/v1/namespaces/my-project/pods/jenkins-2-c1hq2
....
I0222 19:20:47.758306   73184 round_trippers.go:390] Request Headers:
I0222 19:20:47.758311   73184 round_trippers.go:393]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: portforward.k8s.io
I0222 19:20:47.758316   73184 round_trippers.go:393]     User-Agent: oc/v1.6.1+5115d708d7 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/fff65cf
I0222 19:20:47.758321   73184 round_trippers.go:393]     Authorization: Bearer Pqg7xP_sawaeqB2ub17MyuWyFnwdFZC5Ny1f122iKh8
I0222 19:20:47.800941   73184 round_trippers.go:408] Response Status: 101 Switching Protocols in 42 milliseconds
I0222 19:20:47.800963   73184 round_trippers.go:408] Response Status: 101 Switching Protocols in 42 milliseconds
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080

( oc port-forward hangs at this point and never returns)
```

We've found a lot of information about how to get this working under GKE, but
nothing that's really helpful for getting this working for OpenShift Origin on
AWS.  Any ideas?

**Update:**

So we realized that sysdig.com's blog post on deploying OpenShift Origin on AWS was missing some key AWS setup information, so based on [OpenShift Origin's Configuring AWS page](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/configuring_aws.html), we set the following env variables and re-ran the ansible playbook:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='AKIASTUFF'
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='STUFF'
$ export ec2_vpc_subnet='my_vpc_subnet'
$ ansible-playbook -c paramiko -i hosts openshift-ansible/playbooks/byo/config.yml --key-file ~/.ssh/my-aws-stack
```

I think this gets us closer, but creating a load-balancer service now gives us an always-pending IP:

```
$ oc get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
jenkins-lb   172.30.XX.YYY <pending>     8080:31338/TCP      12h
```

The section on [AWS Applying Configuration Changes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/install_config/configuring_aws.html#aws-applying-configuration-changes) seems to imply I need to use AWS Instance IDs rather than hostnames to identify my nodes, but I tried this and OpenShift Origin fails to start if I use that method.  Still at a loss.

Comment: The ``oc port-forward`` command will not return, it will run until you interrupt it. You likely misunderstand what ``oc port-forward`` is for. It is for creating a temporary connection from a pod to your local machine. Once you run it, you would connect to ``127.0.0.1:8080`` to make requests to the application in that pod. You can see an example of using port forwarding in exercises at https://learn.openshift.com.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Ok, so oc port-forward does not actually expose this outside of localhost "loopback" then?  So that particular attempt was barking up the wrong tree then, perhaps.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 you should reconsider assigning Elastic IPs to pods. EIPs can be bound to EC2 instances, not pods. Ideally, you would bind an EIP to the EC2 instance hosting the Openshift router, and expose your Kubernetes service via the router. That way, you can access the service via the hostname specified in the Openshift route.

Comment: @VineetReynolds All the documentation on OpenShift routes and routers led me to believe they were only useful if I had an external-facing domain name, which we don't have at this point.  Unless we can route to the super-long AWS generated hostname? (i.e.: `ec2-18-2AA-BBB-CCC.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`)

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 it's worth trying. You might be better off using a fake hostname. In this case, it is very likely only your browser needs help locating the host - easily resolved through `etc/hosts` entry on client.

Answer (score 0):

It may not satisfy the "Elastic IP" part but how about using [AWS cloud provider ELB](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#load-balancers) to expose the IP/port to the pod via a service to the pod with LoadBalancer option?

1. Make sure to configure the AWS cloud provider for the cluster (References)
2. Create a svc to the pod(s) with type LoadBalancer.

For instance to expose a Dashboard via AWS ELB.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer <-----
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

Then the svc will be exposed as an ELB and the pod can be accessed via the ELB public DNS name a53e5811bf08011e7bae306bb783bb15-953748093.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

```
$ kubectl (oc) get svc kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                              PORT(S)         AGE       SELECTOR
kubernetes-dashboard   LoadBalancer   10.100.96.203   a53e5811bf08011e7bae306bb783bb15-953748093.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com   443:31636/TCP   16m       k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
```

### References

1. [K8S AWS Cloud Provider Notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17d4qinC_HnIwrK0GHnRlD1FKkTNdN__VO4TH9-EzbIY/edit)
2. [Reference Architecture OpenShift Container Platform on Amazon Web Services](https://medium.com/@ngerasimatos/reference-architecture-openshift-container-platform-on-amazon-web-services-b6b6b9103b1e)
3. [DEPLOYING OPENSHIFT CONTAINER PLATFORM 3.5 ON AMAZON WEB SERVICES](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/reference_architectures/2017/html-single/deploying_openshift_container_platform_3.5_on_amazon_web_services/index)
4. [Configuring for AWS](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/install_config/configuring_aws.html)

Comment: Using a LoadBalancer Service was one of the first things we tried, but for some reason that we can't figure out, it's always assigned a non-public IP as the EXTERNAL-IP: `jenkins-lb   172.30.AAA.BBB   172.29.XXX.YYY,172.29.XXX.YYY   8080:30989/TCP`

Comment: If you have kubelet log, please provide.

Comment: Here's the relevant error as reported by journalctl: `for service my-proj/jenkins-lb: InvalidSubnet: Not enough IP space available in subnet-a7ab8fff. ELB requires at least 8 free IP addresses in each subnet.`

Comment: Please make sure of the AWS cloud provider pre-requisites (IAM roles and assign them to EC2 instances) as in K8S AWS Cloud Provider Notes, and the definition of subnet-a7ab8fff, and the CNI (using calico or flannel?)

Answer (score 0):

Check this guide out: https://github.com/dwmkerr/terraform-aws-openshift

It's got some significant advantages vs. the one you referring to in your post. Additionally, it has a clear terraform spec that you can modify and reset to using an Elastic IP (haven't tried myself but should work).

Another way to "lock" your access to the installation is to re-code the assignment of the Public URL to the master instance in the terraform script, e.g., to a domain that you own (the default script sets it to an external IP-based value with "xip.io" added - works great for testing), then set up a basic ALB that forwards https 443 and 8443 to the master instance that the install creates (you can do it manually after the install is completed, also need a second dummy Subnet; dummy-up the healthcheck as well) and link the ALB to your domain via Route53. You can even use free Route53 wildcard certs with this approach.

Comment: I'll give it a look.  As I mentioned in my question, we're just looking to route to a public IP at this point, no DNS (there's a bit of red-tape involved at our company to set up a new domain, so no Route53 yet).  The "xip.io" approach is promising, but not sure our IT security would be a fan of using it for more than a few hours or maybe days, just because they'd want to understand it better ;-).

Comment: So after going through this example, I end up with a similar end result.  In the end, oc get services shows an `EXTERNAL-IP` of `<none>` for any newly created service associated with a running pod.

Comment: The external IP is mapped automatically via a route. This is what I see after deploying a sample blog app from openshift examples  ` NAME          HOST/PORT                      PATH      SERVICES   PORT      TERMINATION     WILDCARD
routes/blog   blog-test01.my-oc.mydomain.com             blog       8080      edge/Redirect   None

NAME       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
svc/blog   172.30.248.171   <none>        8080/TCP   1d`

Comment: Pls see an example here https://github.com/openshift-katacoda/blog-django-py/blob/master/templates/postgresql-persistent-two-volumes.json
"kind": "Route",

Comment: In this setup, the route exposes the service as a prefixed domain at the "Public URL" of the cluster, which is a property of the cluster assigned at its creation. Then you just need a DNS resolution to get to that domain form where you are